Unable to set transparency on GeoTiff images on GeoServer
I have some GeoTiffs (RGBA) with the following Band information obtained using gdalinfo:
Band 1 Block=9x14 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
Band 2 Block=9x14 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 3 Block=9x14 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 4 Block=9x14 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined


 using OpenLayers LayerPreview using GeoServer.
I'm not able to set the black pixels to be transparent. This is for a single Tiff file. The end goal is to have multiple tiff files exposed via WMS as a ImageMosaic. The in-between areas are all black and I'm unable to set them to be transparent.
I have tried the following:

Setting the Input Transparent Color or Output Transparent Color to any value throws exception when I try the preview. Specifically, the exception is as follows:

Caused by: org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported data type.
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.DirectRasterRenderer.render(DirectRasterRenderer.java:303)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:302)
    ... 141 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported data type.
    at org.geotools.image.ImageWorker.makeColorTransparent(ImageWorker.java:2773)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.read(GeoTiffReader.java:787)
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.read(AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.java:262)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.read(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:147)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:234)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:222)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readSingleCoverage(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:643)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readCoverageInEnvelope(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:372)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readCoverages(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:248)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:719)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:668)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.DirectRasterRenderer.readWithProjectionHandling(DirectRasterRenderer.java:722)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.DirectRasterRenderer.render(DirectRasterRenderer.java:247)
    ... 142 more

I see that it says Unsupported data type, does that mean I need to convert my tiffs? If so, to what?
No combination of the solutions available out there seems to work.
Please help
